# mssql Combining rows with similar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have the following view:

```
item_name    2018-1    2018-2   2018-3
windows      null      34       null
windows_old  3         3        44
linux        23        2        null
linux CR     null      null     45
```

I want to combine rows that have similar names into one (along with summing up the numbers on the rows) using regex (for example, combine everything where item_name matches '^windows')

So the end result would be:

```
item_name    2018-1    2018-2   2018-3
windows      3         37       44
linux        23        2        45
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` and `SUM` function. write a subquery to set up similar names.

**Test DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  item_name VARCHAR(50),
  Col1 INT,
  Col2 INT,
  Col3 INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('windows',null,34,null);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('windows_old',3,3,44);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('linux',23,2,null);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('linux CR',null ,null,45);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    new_name as 'item_name',
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE '%'+item_name+'%' THEN Col1 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE '%'+item_name+'%' THEN Col2 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN item_name LIKE '%'+item_name+'%' THEN Col3 END)
FROM (SELECT *,
      coalesce(
            (CASE WHEN item_name LIKE '%windows%' THEN 'windows' END),
            (CASE WHEN item_name LIKE '%linux%' THEN 'linux' END)
       ) new_name 
      FROM T
) t
GROUP BY new_name
```

**Result**

```
| new_name | 2018-1 | 2018-2 | 2018-3 |
|----------|--------|--------|--------|
|    linux |     23 |      2 |     45 |
|  windows |      3 |     37 |     44 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/29540/1)

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information I would suggest a UNION (ALL):

```
SELECT 'windows' AS [Bezeichnung]
    , COUNT/SUM(...) AS [n]
FROM [Object(s)]
WHERE [item_name] LIKE 'windows%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'linux' AS [Bezeichnung]
    , COUNT/SUM(...) AS [n]
FROM [Object(s)]
WHERE [item_name] LIKE 'linux%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, used regex/patIndex

```
SELECT 
        Case patIndex ('%[ _/-]%', LTrim (item_name))
            When 0 Then LTrim (item_name)
            Else substring (LTrim (item_name), 1, patIndex ('%[ _/-]%', LTrim (item_name)) - 1)
        End item,
        SUM([2018-1]) as [2018-1],
        SUM([2018-2]) as [2018-2],
        SUM([2018-3]) as [2018-3]
    FROM T
    GROUP BY Case patIndex ('%[ _/-]%', LTrim (item_name))
            When 0 Then LTrim (item_name)
            Else substring (LTrim (item_name), 1, patIndex ('%[ _/-]%', LTrim (item_name)) - 1)
            END
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63e68/2/0)